# WiFi Hotspot not working with mobile devices on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, hot-spot, windows-phone

WiFi hotspot not working with windows phone 8 and of course its not working with a any other phones as well.
I have tried both Android and Windows phone 8. Either of these devices doesn't even detect Ubuntu's hotspot as I have tried many possible ways..

**Link I referred to:** [How to Turn Your Ubuntu Laptop into a Wireless Access Point](http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/)

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/a/366765/202806.

Comment: **You can try my post here :** **http://askubuntu.com/questions/410509/how-to-make-ubuntu-13-10-a-wi-fi-router/410513#410513** **I tried it and work like a charm !**

Answer (score 0):

From ap-hotspot on github:

> While it may still work, AP-Hotspot is abandoned. [and so on](https://github.com/hotice/AP-Hotspot)

**Solution that worked for me:**

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/

Comment: Was this meant as a reply to the other answer? OP doesn't mention using ap-hotspot but a GUI method. I may be misunderstanding, but if it was intended as a response to the other answer, then it should be a comment on that answer.

Answer (score -1):

i am using ap-hotspot on ubuntu 13.10, it works like charm on my lumia 620. you could give it a try.

Comment: `ap-hotspot` is good... Embedding instructions from [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html) or [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/366765/178596) may make this a better answer.