# How to make ubuntu 13.10 a wi fi router

Tags: wireless, networking, android

I just install ubuntu 13.10, I hope I can make my laptop, which is connected to internet by a cable, as a WiFi router.

I just googled for some ideas, I find a huge access to this topic , I read several articles and I tried several ways , but non of them succeed .

What i need is just some steps to do either by terminal or by creating a new wifi network.

I usually use my phone , `android Samsung ACE` to check if my new network works properly .

Thanks very much , any suggestion would be highly appreciated .